# How to enable gyroscope in GeckoView

Tags: android, webview, gyroscope, gecko, geckoview

In one of my projects, I am trying to use GeckoView as a replacement of WebView to support WebGL for all devices possible. However GeckoView does not respond to the device gyroscope as default WebView already does.

Could anyone help me to enable gyroscope in GeckoView?

Comment: What do you mean by "respond to the device gyroscope"?

Comment: @DougStevenson web view navigates to a url in which a javascript function is executed to handle the device's gyroscope. Actually in that url, a VR player is working out to give users guided tours of the interiors. So the VR player functions to respond to the motion sensors if you are using a smartphone. However, as I mentioned above, GeckoView seems to be ignoring this function while the default WebView does not.